Fixing mypy error - Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "xxx", variable has type "yyy")
I am running into the following mypy error and cannot figure out how to fix it.
test.py:30: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "list[str] | list[Path]", variable has type "list[Path]")  [assignment]

Code versions: Python 3.10.13, mypy 1.9.0 (compiled: yes)
I tried options 1 and 2 from the accepted answer here, but that didn't do anything.
Here's the code:
import re
import glob
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Sequence


def find_files(files: str | Sequence[str], sort: bool = True) -> list[str] | list[Path]:
    """Find files based on shell-style wildcards.
    
    files = '/path/to/all/*.csv'

    files = [
        '/path/to/all/*.csv',
        '/and/to/all/*.xlsx
    ]
    """

    # Convert to list if input is a str.
    files = [files] if isinstance(files, str) else files

    # Find files.
    found_files = [Path(fglob).resolve()
                   for f in files
                   for fglob in glob.glob(f, recursive=True)]

    # Make sure no duplicates exist.
    found_files = [*set(found_files)]

    if sort:
        found_files = sort_nicely(found_files) # TODO: mypy complains here

    return found_files


def sort_nicely(lst: Sequence[str] | Sequence[Path] ) -> list[str] | list[Path]:
    """Perform natural human sort.
    
    sort_nicely(['P1', 'P10', 'P2']) == ['P1', 'P2', 'P10'] 
    """

    def convert(text: str) -> str | int:
        return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

    def alpha_key(item: str | Path) -> list[str | int]:
        return [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', str(item))]

    return sorted(lst, key=alpha_key)


Note that alpha_key is too general; values of type list[str | int] aren't generally comparable, e.g. ["foo"] < [3] raises a TypeError.

In general, don't worry about special cases that the caller can easily handle. Don't worry about accepting a single str argument; just let the caller be responsible for using find_files(["foo"]) instead of accommodating find_files("foo").

You need to describe the type of your sort_nicely function better, like this:
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar("T", bound=str|Path)
def sort_nicely(lst: Sequence[T] ) -> list[T]:
    ...

What your signature is saying is "function may take a sequence of str or Path and returns a list of str or Path". What this is saying is "function may take a sequence of str or Path and return a list of the same thing".

str|Path is probably too tight: sort_nicely works with anything on any type T whose values can be converted to strings. Really, it should probably just accept Sequence[str], and the caller can be responsible for ensuring the conversion to str is done. Or, if sort_nicely is only used by find_files, it only ever gets called with lists of Path values and so could be typed accordingly.

@chepner Might be. This is not a holistic code-review, I literally just tried this change in my editor to see if it makes the file mypy-clean and it did. I can see in a few places of the code that OP doesn't seem to use generics when they could so I figured it would be helpful to point them to this system.

@julaine This fixed the mypy error. Thank you! I'll have to look into TypeVar more because I don't know what it does exactly, but it works.

@Simon1 the general concept is called "Generics", that is probably easier to search for than TypeVar. Lots of guides out there (and the concept is not exclusive to python), can't give you a recommendation because the 'best' explanation really depends on your prior experience.

The problem is that mypy tracks the types of the variables and does not expect it to change (even though it is possible in Python).

When you write :
found_files = [Path(fglob).resolve()
                   for f in files
                   for fglob in glob.glob(f, recursive=True)]

mypy will assign automatically the type List[Path] to found_files.
Then, when you write
found_files = sort_nicely(found_files)

mypy has in mind that found_files is of type List[Path], but the result of sort_nicely is List[str] | List[Path].

An easy solution would be to avoid reusing the same variables, like so :
found_files = [Path(fglob).resolve()
                   for f in files
                   for fglob in glob.glob(f, recursive=True)]

found_files_no_duplicates = [*set(found_files)]

if not sort:
    return found_files_no_duplicates

return sort_nicely(found_files_no_duplicates)

Another would be to modify sort_nicely such that it returns a List[Path] only (I guess that would mean taking a List[Path] only as an input ?)
